# Access single xml file using different activity in android

Tags: android-layout, android-intent

Now I develop a multiplayer (In a single device) game and countdown Timer seperatly. The game have 1 Activity and 1 xml,and countdown timer also have 1 activity and 1 xml. I want to add the timer inside the game  and in new project I design a new xml file that containing game board and timer.How to access this single xml file using Game activity and countdown timer activity?